# Validity of "this" in destructor

Tags: c++

On the last line of a destructor, I have a diagnostic type message which takes a `printf`-like form:

```
"object destroyed at %p", this
```

I have concerns though about how well `this` is defined at such a point.

Should I have such reservations? Is the behaviour well-defined?

Comment: it'll get destroyed when it returns from the destructor so it should still be valid

Comment: *should* or *is*? I'll be in a lot of trouble if I introduce UB.

Comment: Is valid, you could just test this yourself

Comment: On my platform indeed I could. I could test `i = ++i` at the same time. But that is no guide at all to *defined* behaviour.

Comment: It would depend on whether the destructor is `non-trivial` see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611468/lifetime-of-object-is-over-before-destructor-is-called. In the case of normal destructor the object lifetime ends when you return from the destructor. If it happened once you enter the body then you wouldn't be able to release member resources

Comment: Reopened - the linked "duplicate" wondered whether you can call functions using `this`, whereas this is much more restricted. In particular, no assumption is made here about members still existing, just the memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (12.4 Destructors)

> 8 **After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body**, a destructor for class
>   X calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data
>   members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes and, if X is the
>   type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for X’s virtual base classes.

So your code is well-formed. All destructors of non-static data members and base classes are called after executing the body of the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the pointer itself certainly still exists (it's just an address, after all). There should be no problem to print the pointer value.

On the other hand, everything that you did in the destructor has already happened. Attributes may already have been `delete`'d, etc, so you have to avoid anything that accesses those.

Comment: +1, the core question here is whether the pointer still has a meaningful value, not whether it can be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

This has perfectly well defined behaviour.  Consider that the `this` pointer can be used implicitly or explicitly throughout the destructor, e.g. whenever you access a member variable for things like `delete ptr_;`.  ***After*** the destructor returns, the members are destroyed in reverse order of declaration/creation then the base destructors invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As you might now, you can access your class members from the destructor. This would not be working if the `this` pointer was invalid. So you can safely assume that the address `this` points to is still the same that you might have printed in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the destructor the `this` pointer is well defined, as are all the members and bases (that will be destroyed in construction reverse order after the destructor return). So printing the address it refers is not UB.

The only thing is that the object itself cannot be assumed anymore as "polymorphic", since the *derived* components had already been destroyed.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void fn() { std::cout << "A::fn" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~A() { fn(); } //< will call A::fn(), even if B is destroying
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void fn() { std::cout << "B::fn" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~B() {}    
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    a.fn(); //< will print B::fn(), being A::fn virtual and being B the runtime-type of the a's referred object
    return 0; //< will print A::fn() from b's A's component destructor
}
```